# Is there any such way (analytically or computationally) to solve this system?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have to fit some data to a nonlinear least squares fit. In doing so I need an initial guess for the function $y(\sigma)= x_1(x_2\sigma)^{x_3}$ . With some the data I get the following set of equations:

$x_1(x_2)^{x_3} = 3.29$

$x_1(2x_2)^{x_3} = 4.3$

$x_1(4x_2)^{x_3} = 7.17$

Is there any way of getting an initial guess for these values using analytical or numerical methods?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find values $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that those three equations are true? Or approximately true?

Comment: The question does not look clear. Could you clarify what are the parameters, covariates,...?

Comment: Approximately true

Comment: If you divide the second equation by the first, you get $2^{x_3}=4.3/3.29\approx 1.307$.
If you divide the third equation by the second, you get $2^{x_3}=7.17/4.3\approx 1.667$.
You have two conflicting requirements for $x_3$, so you can take your pick on how to resolve it.

Comment: Just parameters

Comment: Take the first, it only has to be rough. It will be used as an initial guess in the Newton Gauss method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x_2$ is extraneous.  You can write $y(\sigma)=x_1x_2^{x_3}\sigma^{x_3}$ and define $x_1'=x_1x_2^{x_3}$ to get down to two parameters.  Now you have a standard exponential fit.  If you take the log of the equation it becomes linear:
$$\log y(\sigma)=\log (x_1')+x_3 \log(\sigma)$$
Now you have an analytic solution if you are happy with least squares in the logs.

Comment: Thank you for this